# Display tax in woocommerce cart widget product same like checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, widget, checkout, tax

I want to display tax on woocommerce shop page side bar cart widget product list same like checkout page.

Current checkout page -> http://nimb.ws/kbn6mL

Shop page side bar woocommerce cart widget -> http://nimb.ws/JVfMtH

So if anyone knows this solution then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your woocomerce tax setting tab that you have selected Display tax totals as single total then it will show you on cart page.

https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1178235/8f9h105gwa5mz3cle7vv

Comment: Yes, that i have already selected. I have using woocommerce cart widget->http://nimb.ws/Rq6deB on this side bar -> http://nimb.ws/Q30ctJ. 

So please review above both screen shot and update me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see Woocommerce itself displays only cart subtotal on cart widget or mini cart, there will be no setting for this to enable/disable for displaying not only tax but shipping as well. So if you want to add tax and shipping related data on mini cart widget then you can add your functionality on this hook 'woocommerce_widget_shopping_cart_before_buttons' by fetching data from the WC->cart

Comment: Hi @Logan Young, Thanks for your replay. Can you please inform me above hook solutions for showing tax on woocommerce widget mini cart.

Thanks.

Comment: As you would not be sure what tax settings the admin has set for taxes like incuding or exclusive tax. You have to first fetch if tax is inc or exc then accordingly display your tax below cart subtotal.